# Initialize model with integer array in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql

I'm using postgres 9.6.1, Rails 4.2.0, and the following migration:

```
class CreateStageBatches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :stage_batches do |t|
      t.text :item_ids, array: true, default: []
    end
  end
end
```

How do I create an array of integers? I've tried:

```
[9] pry(main)> StageBatch.new item_ids: [1,2,3]
=> #<StageBatch id: nil, item_ids: ["1", "2", "3"]>
```

But they are strings.

Looking at the postgres [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html) it looks like this is possible but I'm not sure what the syntax is for my migration or instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 t.integer 'item_ids', array: true
```